# Creating a server side for android application

Tags: java, web-services, rest, sockets, server

I'm currently making an android application that will be used by a certain number of clients. Each client will have an account and will access information from the server. This information is stored in a DB.

My question is what is the best way to create a server side that will, later on, be compatible with other platforms (iOS, Windows, etc.)? 
Can I use sockets on different platforms? Or should I create a Web Service?
I found a certain tutorial that I think is explaining a similar thing, but I think it demands a certain amount of knowledge, and I'm totally new to this, and haven't learned this at faculty (I'm good with sockets but I never had much confidence in them, and the idea of sending HTTP requests to the server looks much better).

Can someone divert me to a tutorial or lectures of how this is supposed to be done?

Comment: Actually tcp sockets are high level networking, not low level. Reading, and writing to sockets is about the same as reading, and writing to a file. If you want low level networking then feel free to use raw sockets.

Comment: I would like to use sockets, but I'm not sure if I can use them on different platforms at client side, that is, can a server socket in java communicate with a client socket in for example objective C for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection between Android and a server would most easily be done with http requests.
There are several libraries available who make this easy like [Retrofit](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/).

For server-side applications you can take a look at [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) in combination with a tomcat server.

There are of course many applications who can do these... so it comes down to a matter of preference.

Comment: Can you explain what sort of connection there is between Jersey and tomcat server?

Comment: Tomcat server will be the server. You can use a java project which runs on tomcat that uses jersey to receive http requests and handles them.

Comment: Can Jersey be used for other platforms?

Comment: I think it's java specific. What platform do you use?

Comment: I want to do it for android at the beginning but in recent future I want to do it for iOS and Windows as well.

Comment: Jersey is the library for the server side. On the tomcat server. So Android, iOS and windows have nothing to do with it. Retrofit is the library for Android, but as far as I know it's limited to Android. You'll [probably end up using different libraries for all of them sooner or later. You can try looking at https://xamarin.com/ this is a framework that lets you develop for Android, iOS and Windows at the same time.

Comment: Yes I understand that, so my question is, can client applications written in different languages all communicate with my Jersey Web Service on tomcat server?

Comment: Http requests are based on text-input like JSON and XML. It's platform independant

Comment: I thought so, but then I saw a tutorial in which some custom objects (POJOs?) were being transfered, and that got me confused. How can an object in java be get the same form in objective C? Or is that whole thing encapsulated and it is actually sending JSON that represents an object?

Comment: It's most likely being parsed as json string. Easy way to do is with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) which literally as you described converts POJOs to Json string

Comment: Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

There are many web development frameworks that works on many platforms such as spring, vertx, play and many others to name. You can you create rest like api for this purpose. Give all the low level works to the framework. You should not worry about low level details as most off them are handled by frameworks today.